# How to do a redirect in Laravel for ads.txt

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5, adsense

Google wants have access to ads.txt file like "example.com/ads.txt", but in Laravel we need redirect it to "public" folder.

How do it?

I try `RedirectMatch 301 ^ads\.txt$ \/public\/ads\.txt`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create blade file has name `ads.blade.php` and put all text from `ads.txt` to this blade , and create route like that :

```
Route::get('/ads.txt',function(){
   return view('ads');
});
```

I tried that when register my website in google

Comment: did you get approved with this method?

Answer (score 6):

Put your ads.txt file in the folder: public (for Laravel), then it will be accessible to the link: example.com/ads.txt . I have made on my laravel website and it's working fine

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue in following way.

In my web route file:

```
Route::get('/ads.txt', function () {
    $content = view('ads');
    return response($content, 200)
        ->header('content-Type', 'text');
});
```

and I have rename the ads.txt file to **ads.blade.php**

Or Simply add your ads.txt file inside public folder of your application it will work fine.

Comment: Simply add your ads.txt file inside public folder of your application it will work fine

This works for me, thanks :)